# Instants vs planeswalker abilities

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you use an instant such as [Sarkhan's Catharsis](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%27s%5d%2b%5bCatharsis%5d) to kill a Planeswalker before they can use an ability?

Comment: Please add some clarification about when during the game you are asking about. Do you mean when a player has first played a Planeswalker, and you want to use an instant before that player has a chance to activate any of the new Planeswalker's abilities?

Comment: Yeah I mean when they first play a planeswalker, I’m kind of new to magic the gathering but I mean in the main phase if that’s the clarification your looking for